# Value check when set not changed

Tags: c#, winforms, events, numericupdown

Is there an event I can use for whenever the value of a `NumericUpDown` Control is set. Not just changed because alot of the times it is set programatically to the same value but the event still needs to be called.

Edit: I mean its not very complicated code its just there's alot of it. because this is pretty much the same for all the body parts

```
private void NumUpDownLeftHandDirection_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    game.Ragdoll.LeftHand.DirectionOffset = (float)NumUpDownLeftHandDirection.Value;
    game.Ragdoll.Direction = game.Ragdoll.Direction;
    MainTimeLine.Frames[MainTimeLine.CurrentFrame].LeftHandDirection = (float)NumUpDownLeftHandDirection.Value;
}
```

I could just put it all in properties but that will be alot of work since I've already coded this expecting it to work.

Comment: show your numericupdown event code ...

Comment: what do you mean about **but the event still needs to be called** ?

Comment: You could make your own Property() in your Form to handle setting the NumericUpDown().

Comment: @matzone if NumUpDownLeftHandDirection value is 0 and i run this command NumUpDownLeftHandDirection.Value = 0; the ValueChanged event is not called, or i should say invoked.